# Can't see published FAQ posts in my wordpress theme site

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WordPress site, which has a page for FAQ, where I m ought to publish some faq posts. but After adding a post and publishing them, although the status shows visible and public, published. but it isn't showing on the site when viewed.

I tried changing permalink and deleting and reading the post. none worked.

Any help is appreciated.

**FAQ Page template :**

```
<?php
/* Template Name: FAQ's */
get_header();

if( have_posts() ): 

    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class("two-tone-layout size-2 left-sidebar"); ?>>

            <div class="equal-content-sidebar faq_page">

                <div class="container">

                    <div class="sidebar-wrapper">

                        <aside>
                            <?php 
                            $cat = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'faq_categories' , true ); 
                            ?>
                            <div class="faq-category">
                                <h4 class="uppercase"><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'faq_sidebar_title' , true ) ); ?></h4>
                                <div class="content">
                                    <ul id="faqTab" class="clearfix" role="tablist">

                                        <?php 
                                        if( !empty($cat) ){ 

                                            $first_key = key($cat);
                                            foreach( $cat as $key => $value ){ 

                                                $active = ( $first_key == $key ? 'active' : '' ); 

                                                $category = get_term_by( 'id' , $value , 'faq_cat' ); 
                                                //print_r($category);

                                                // Hide empty category
                                                if( $category->count != 0 ){ ?>

                                                    <li role="presentation" class="<?php echo esc_html( $active ); ?>">
                                                        <a href="#faqTab<?php echo esc_html( $key ); ?>" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true"><?php echo esc_html( $category->name ); ?></a>
                                                    </li>

                                                    <?php

                                                }

                                            } 

                                        } ?>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </aside>

                    </div>

                    <div class="content-wrapper">

                        <div class="section-title mb-20">
                            <h2 class="mb-15 text-left"><?php echo esc_html( get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'faq_main_title' , true ) ); ?></h2>
                        </div>

                        <div class="bb"></div>
                        <div class="bb"></div>

                        <?php 
                        $contentPosition = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'faq_add_content' , true ); 

                        if( $contentPosition == 2 ){  
                            the_content(); 
                        } ?>

                        <div class="tab-content mt-10 mb-30">

                            <?php 

                            if( !empty($cat) ){  

                                $layout = get_post_meta( $post->ID , 'faq_layout' , true ); // Accordion Layout
                                $first_key = key($cat);

                                foreach( $cat as $key => $value ){ 

                                    $active = ( $first_key == $key ? 'active' : '' ); 

                                    $category = get_term_by( 'id' , $value , 'faq_cat' );

                                    // Hide empty category
                                    if( $category->count != 0 ){  ?>

                                        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane <?php echo esc_html( $active ); ?>" id="faqTab<?php echo esc_html( $key ); ?>">

                                            <?php extretion_getFaqCategoryPost( $value , $key , $layout ); ?>                               
                                        </div>

                                        <?php 

                                    }

                                }                           

                            } ?>

                        </div>

                        <?php 
                        if( $contentPosition == 1 ){  
                            the_content(); 
                        } 
                        ?>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    <?php

    endwhile;

endif;

get_footer();
```

FAQ screenshots in dashboard

[FAQ DB table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LgbC.png)

Comment: Have you created any specific template for displaying faqs? if yes, then which code are you using? please clarify with details and if possible share your URL.

Comment: It actually came along with the template. In admin dashboard, there is this FAQ option with Add New option. and Categories option. where we assign each post with a category.  I tried adding new category along with post and assign them together. yet nothing.

Comment: `http://imgproofers.com/faqs/` is the url of the site, although it shows  empty

Comment: I think the problem is in your code inside the page-template-faq template which used for this page.  Please go through the code and check what is the issue actually.

Comment: @GajjarChintan I have added the Faq template code to the question. can you please check it once. i hardly understand any of that..

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is starting from here: `if( !empty($cat) ) {`

$cat array is empty and is coming from this code:

`$cat = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'faq_categories' , true );`

That means you haven't created any `faq_categories` yet. Just create the faq category and assign that category to your created faq.

try to check with `echo '<pre>';print_r($cat)` and check again. if it will not be empty then your content will be displayed.

Hope this will helpful for you. Thanks.

Comment: yeah i tried adding a category and assigning the same to the faq content. yet nothing displayed..

Comment: Are you getting anything inside this array after creating category: echo '<pre>';print_r($cat) ?  Try with adding this code below $cat = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'faq_categories' , true );  this one

Comment: actually i don't know how to see that.. but when I add a category and assign it , i see empty faq page.

Comment: "faq_categories"  this is the custom field and you need to add a category by using this field from your backend faq page. Right now the problem is you are creating a category from somewhere else sure @Harish.

Comment: Can you please edit the code in a way that i don't need categories instead post all faq content as it is without showing the categories on the side... Please bro

Comment: Can you please send me the full screenshot of your backend where you added faq content and passing category?

Comment: This is the blank post. Seems like you haven't created any category yet. Send me the screenshot of published faq post with assigned category. You can send me here in a comment.

Comment: added the new screenshots to the question. Yet nothing is shown in the site faq page... Please take a look bro.

Comment: No need to modified or change your code. Just you are missing something in your page setting from backend. I have to see your setting inside your faq page, not in the post. That's the way can solve your problem. Try to check in your database wp_postmeta table and check meta_key = faq_categories. check data exist or not

Comment: please check the updated the screenshot in the question. there are two mentions of "Faq_categories" in the meta key tab.. please take a look.